# The ideal generated by the set $I \cup \{a\}$.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ a commutative ring with identity.  For some $a \in R$, prove that the ideal generated by $I \cup \{a\}$, denoted $(I,a) = \{ i + ra \mid i \in I \text{ and } r \in R\}$.  My text book says that for a subset $S$ of a ring $R$ that $(S)=\bigcap\{I\mid S \in I\text{ and }I \text { is an ideal of R}\}$.  How is this going to help me make this proof?  Am I supposed to prove that $(I,a) $is the smallest ideal of $R$ that contains $I \cup \{a\}$.  If so, what is the structure of such a proof.  What steps must I show?  This is for a homework assignment so please do not give the proof.  I think what might help is an example of a similar proof.

Comment: You didn't finish your second sentence.  Did you mean "For some $a \in R$, prove that the ideal generated by $I \cup \{a\}$, denoted $(I,a)$, is $\{ i + ra \mid i \in I \text{ and } r \in R\}$."? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes,thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{I}$ be the set of ideals of $R$ containing $I\cup\{a\}$ as a subset. First show that if $J\in\mathscr{I}$, then $i+ra\in J$ for each $i\in I$ and $r\in R$; this will show that

$$\{i+ra:i\in I\text{ and }r\in R\}\subseteq\bigcap\mathscr{I}=(I,a)\;.$$

Then show that $\{i+ra:i\in I\text{ and }r\in R\}$ is an ideal; this will show that

$$\{i+ra:i\in I\text{ and }r\in R\}\in\mathscr{I}$$

and hence that

$$(I,a)=\bigcap\mathscr{I}\subseteq\{i+ra:i\in I\text{ and }r\in R\}\;.$$

Comment: OK.  So structurally this is a set equality proof.   I am concerned that in my "proof"  I did NOT use the fact that R has an identity.  Is the statement true if R does not have an identity?

Comment: Upon further reflection, I think that in my first "proof" I failed to demonstrate that {i + ra: i in I and r in R} contains I union {a}.  This is where R must have an identity so that a itself is certainly in  {i + ra: i in I and r in R}.

Comment: @Geoffrey: Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly, you are supposed to prove that $(I,a):=\{i+ra\mid i\in I,\,r\in R,\,a\in A\}$ is the smallest ideal of $R$ that contains $I$ and $a$.

1. Prove that $(I,a)$ is an ideal.
2. Note that it contains $I\cup\{a\}$.
3. Prove that any ideal $J$ that contains $I$ and $a$, also contains $(I,a)$.